# Change Label width of checkbox in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have created list with checkbox , Check demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Y7AJe/ ... now if you hover your mouse over the checkbox there is label around it . I need to change width of that label.

[image]

When i inspect element i see label inherits ui-btn style.So I tried something like below,but its not working.

```
label .ui-btn
{
width : "30px";
}
```

And i also tried to add `style="width: 30px;"` to label and input .. Still its not working.

Comment: you have almost everything absolute positioned.

Comment: @Jai : how to fix that ?